# Data container for fast lookup and retrieval

Tags: c++

Actually I need a data structure that helps me in reducing time for look-ups and retrieval of values of the respective keys.

Right now I am using a map container with key as structure and want to retrieve its values as fast as possible.

I am using gcc on fedora 12. I tried unordered map also, but it is not working with my compiler.

Also, Hash map is not available in namespace `std`.

Comment: can you elaborate on your keys, key space, values, and value space?

Comment: In what way is `unordered_map` not working?

Comment: To get `std::unordered_map` you need to compile for `C++11`. You can do that by specifying `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: not if you use boost, that will work with c++03

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using C++11, use `std::unordered_map`, defined in `<unordered_map>`.

Otherwise, use `std::tr1::unordered_map`, defined in `<tr1/unordered_map>`, or `boost::unordered_map`, defined in `<boost/unordered_map.hpp>`.

If your key is a user-defined type, then you'll need to either define `hash` and `operator==` for the type, or provide suitable function types as template arguments to `unordered_map`.

Of course, you should also measure the performance compared to `std::map`; that may be faster in some circumstances.

Comment: Thanks alot :) i am trying to use unordered maps.

Comment: actually to use boost hashmap i will have to download a lot of libraries ...i want something easy to use..unordered map should prove helpful to me ..i'll try and get back to this ..Thanks alot .

Comment: @user1087895: You'll only need Boost if you need to support compilers that don't provide `<tr1/unordered_map>`. If you're only using GCC, then you should already have that.

Answer (score 0):

hash map is called unordered_map. You can get it from [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html) and that will probably work even if you can't get a std/tr1 one to work. In general the lookup time is "constant" which means it does not increase with the complexity of the nubmer of elements. However you have to look at this in more detail:

- "constant" assumes you never have more than a fixed number of "collisions". It's unlikely you won't have any, and then you have to measure the fact that there will be some collisions.
- "constant" includes the time taken to hash the key. This is a constant time as it makes no difference how many other elements there are in the collection, however it is still a task that needs to be done, by which time your std::map may already have found your element.

If the keys are extremely fast to hash and well distributed so very few collisions occur, then hashing will indeed be faster.

One thing I always found when working with hash maps was that for the optimal performance you almost always won by writing your own implementation rather than using a standard one. That is because you could custom-tune your own for the data you knew you were going to handle. Perhaps this is why they didn't put hash maps into the original standard.

One thing I did when writing my own was store the actual hash value (the originally generated one) with the key. This was the first comparison point (usually faster than comparing the key as it's just an int) and also meant it didn't need to be regenerated if you resized your hash-table.

Note that hash-tables are easier to implement if you never delete anything from them, i.e. it is load and read only.

Comment: Yes ,that is what i want to confirm that the overhead of time taken to hash the key will result in more time than std::map or not.

Comment: This will commonly depend on the size of your map and the comparison time for each node. Remember you will have some comparisons on a hash map too as you get collisions (a flat table with reassigned collisions is the most common way to implement).